# Groovy/Hydro on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the title says everything. I just want to know if it's possible to install ros groovy and hydro under ubuntu 14.04. Any thoughts or ideas?

I'm working now with ubuntu 12.04 and I use groovy and hydro, and they work nicely, the problem is the drivers for my computer (video card, sound card, etc), so that's the reason why I would like to know about the configuration of groovy (and hydro) under ubuntu 14.04. Have anybody some experience with that? even if it's the compiled source, in order to know if it's working properly under that configuration.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186649/groovy/hydro-on-ubuntu-14.04?/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I have no experience with Groovy on 14.04, I guess there will be some problems.

For one it seems that groovy cannot be fully built from source currently without additional tweaks: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4792

I understand that you might need groovy for legacy systems, but as a recent answer to a related question described, groovy will soon be EOL: http://answers.ros.org/question/186722/should-i-use-hydro-or-indigo-for-my-new-project/?answer=186831#post-id-186831

Also, the same question popped up about the same time you asked yours: http://answers.ros.org/question/186676/groovy-install-in-ubuntu-1404/

So, if you cannot do without groovy, it is best to try it out on 14.04 (e.g. in a VM) and contribute back any fixes you need to make.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-07-19**:
Actually I only use groovy because I use the PR2, and the full support for the PR2 is only on groovy. Things like tuckarms have no packages yet under hydro for example. But well, I guess you're right to also have a VM to test and create fixes.